# Data from a Range to a Corresponding Range in New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need a code that will look at each column, of each worksheet, in a workbook ("Master"), copy the data to a new worksheet ("Sheet1"), and create four entries of each data point.  I need the data to copy to certain columns in the new worksheet; for example, I need the data in column T of Sheets("Australia") to copy to column S in Sheets("Sheeet1"), column V to column U, etc.).

The end result should look like:

```
Workbooks("Master").Sheets("Australia")
Column T  Column V
1         4
2         5
3         6
```

becomes...

```
Workbooks("NewWB").Sheets("Sheet1")
Column S Column U
1        4
1        4  
1        4
1        4
2        5
2        5
2        5
2        5
...      ...
```

I have already tried:

```
Sub Populate()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ShtNames(1 To 75) As String
Dim y As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Add
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    .Range("B1").Value = "Language"

End With

y = 1
For Each WS In Workbooks("Master").Worksheets
ShtNames(y) = WS.Name
y = y + 1
Next WS

'Languages
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Activate
    For y = LBound(ShtNames) To UBound(ShtNames)
    For Each Cell In Workbooks("Master").Sheets(ShtNames(y)).Range("AT6:AT160")
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
                For Rownum = 1 To 4
                    ActiveCell.Value = Cell.Value
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Next Rownum
    End If
    Next Cell
    Next y

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Displayalerts = True

End Sub
```

My problem is that this becomes a very long, clunky code.  I need to repeat this same process for several headings ("Lanuages," "ID Num", "Territory", etc.) and I am seeking a way to use dynamic ranges and variables instead of named ranges.

I'm a VBA beginner; anything you experts have for me would be greatly appreciated!!  Thanks very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You will get a much better response to your question if you can show what you have already attempted.

Comment: Thanks PaulStock!  Updated just now.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this will point you in the right direction. The code below is copying from one sheet to another within the same workbook, but you can modify to copy to a different workbook:

```
    Dim src As Range
    Dim Col1, Col2
    Dim DestRow As Integer

    Set src = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(1, 20).CurrentRegion
    DestRow = 1    ' the destination starting row
    For SourceRow = 1 To srcRow.Rows.Count
        Col1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(SourceRow, 20)   ' column T
        Col2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(SourceRow, 22)   ' column V

        ' copy to destination sheet 4 times
        For x = 1 To 4
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(DestRow, 19) = Col1  ' column S
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(DestRow, 21) = Col2  ' column U
            DestRow = DestRow + 1
        Next
    Next
```

Hope this gives you some ideas on how to use dynamic ranges within loops.

Comment: This looks great. thank you!  It's giving me an "Object Required" error, though, right at line "For SourceRow = 1 To srcRow.Rows.Count".  Any thoughts?